# How to be as fair as possible to conduct SQL query performance test?

Tags: sql, performance, sql-server-2008

I am using SQL server 2008 R2 and am trying to test the performance of some SQL queries with different writing style. These involve udfs, views, inline, join, pivot, etc.

After quite a bit of testings, I can say that udfs are super slow, so now I expanded them into my queries. But as the performance test went on, it became much harder to tell the difference because I had been getting inconsistent results.

Like for example, I tested a query full of joins and one that moves some joins to inline select. The inline style performed better and better until I moved all the joins to inline selects, it performed much worst than the original.

Another thing is the execution time, which is highly unreliable. For the same query, the execution time varies and inconsistent as well. Like when I opened up the SQL Profiler, even I saw a higher CPU time, Reads, Writes, the execution time can be quicker!

I really need a good method as fair as possible to test the SQL queries. Execution plan doesn't help. I need numbers like CPU cycles(not elapse time), Reads, Writes, Memory, something I can calculate and are consistent. And I need a way to force the same testing environment. I tried DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS, but thats not helping.

Thank you!

Comment: If you generate actual plans from within [SQL Sentry Plan Explorer](http://sqlsentry.net/plan-explorer/sql-server-query-view.asp), it will give you actual runtime metrics, wait stats (with PRO only), and take away some of the variable noise (since, for example, we discard results instead of transferring them to the client, which can skew measurements). *Disclaimer: I work for SQL Sentry.* Depending on the server, actual runtimes will vary from execution to execution, and sometimes these defy explanation, but this should take away some of the variables.

Comment: When you run DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS you should run CHECKPOINT first. DBCC FREEPROCCACHE might interest you as well.

Comment: Thank you, I will throw in DBCC FREEPROCCACHE, DBCC FREESYSTEMCACHE('ALL') this time as well.